# Is there a way to change the Local name of a BLE advertisement?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to change the local name of my BLE advertisemnt (I use BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher and BluetoothLEManufacturerData).

I already saw that it's not possible here : [system-reserved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementpublisher?view=winrt-22621)

I would like to know if anyone had a way to bypass that because I really need to have a custom local name in my advertising.

Here the code I have:

```
        publisher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher();

        var manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData();

        manufacturerData.CompanyId = 0xCA21;

        var writer = new DataWriter();
        string dataString = "UPD|0172|4|8|0236|2|1|0395|4|0564|4|8|0772|4|2|0428|4|2|";
        byte[] manufacturerString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
        writer.WriteBytes(manufacturerString);

        manufacturerData.Data = writer.DetachBuffer();

        publisher.UseExtendedAdvertisement = true;

        BluetoothAdapter testt = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();


        Debug.WriteLine("IsExtendedAdvertisingSupported = " + testt.IsExtendedAdvertisingSupported);

        publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);
```

Comment: If you are just looking to change it locally, you can manually change the name via the Device Manager. Find your PC's Bluetooth adapter, open its properties, and the name is modifiable under Advanced.
I looked at the Radio and BluetoothDevice classes and those are all read-only for their name.